# Find hidden/covered elements in SVG

Tags: svg

Is there a way to check if an element is completely covered in SVG?
I'm not talking about display:none, visibility:hidden or element out of the viewport.
I'm trying to find out if an element is completely not visible because other SVG elements are in front of it.

It'll be better if I can do it in browsers but on the server side with an SVG lib will be OK too.

Thanks